# c++ difference between std::string name and std::string &name

Tags: c++

I have a lib.h, lib.cpp and test.cpp. I would like to ask what is better?
lib.h

```
class c
{
    std::string name;
}*cc;
```

lib.cpp

```
{
    std::cout << "the name is:" << name << std:: endl;
}
```

test.cpp

```
main()
{ 
    c tst;
    tst.name="diana";
}
```

What should I use? std::string name or std::string *name? How can i work with &name, how will my code change and which one of these 2 methods is the best one?

Comment: Edited the code mess: Coding style matters. If you don't bother to even format your code, you cannot hope for sudden '_understanding_' to happen miraculously

Comment: where am i wrong in the eq code i've posted?

Comment: Don't believe ubuntu tag really belong here. Removed it.

Comment: I just cleaned it up. Indents, spacing, namespace qualifiers. Nothing was 'wrong', it was just not very readable, and unreadable code _will_ cause you to make more bugs than you can fix (I bet you hadn't even realized, you were declaring a variable `cc` as a pointer to `c`?)

Comment: see my answer. Your code actually has an error. In your `main` function you try to modify private member `name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I hardly believe your code will compile while in your `main` you try to get access to private data member `name`.

About `&`. It is really hard to define where to start. In short `std::string &name` is called `reference` to object of type `std::string`. Reference is somehow an *alias* to some other object. The main feature is, that you always have to initialize refence to object while creating and you can't reinitialize reference to point to another object. More about this feature you can read in [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references)

**EDIT**
Generally you can declare public, protected and private members of your class in with arbitrary ordering:

```
class MyClass {
//here goes private members when working with class
//and public when working with structs

public:
//here goes public members
protected:
//here goes protected
private: 
//here goes private
public: 
//here goes public again
};
```

Ordering of members declaration is actually code policy question. For example, [google style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Access_Control) recommends to put all `public` members before `private`.

About hiding function members (not necessary private). You actually can't hide function member declaration, but there are several ways to "hide" implementation, but I am not sure that it's the definition of hiding you are talking about. But you can check [PImpl](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29) idiom. This requires understanding of pointers so I advice you to start with them first.

Small code sample for working with pointer to string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyClass {
public:
 std::string *pstr;
};

int main() {
 std::string str("test");
 MyClass myObj;

 myObj.pstr = &str;
 std::cout << myObj.pstr->c_str()  << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer. WHat about std::string *name;? And one more thing? If I add public to my class from .h file how can I define a private method called bool print(std::string name)? Is there a way define and work with the method without seing it in the .h file? because it's a private method i want to find a solution to not puting it in the .h

Comment: See my reedited post for your question about public/private declaration. About `std::string *name` - this is called a pointer to string and more about differences between pointers and references you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c).

Comment: and if i want MyClass to be public how to do it? public: class MyClass{.....}*myclass?

Comment: One more thing. In the header file I don't want to be seen the private methods :). I mean I don't want to have private: method(int x);

Comment: No, it's right syntax. In this case you can write `class MyClass {public: /**/};`. But if you want to have the whole class public consider using `struct` instead of class. `struct` members are public by default.

Comment: can you please reeditate my code using in the header std::string *name. How could I call this from main?Please add a private method that is not declared in the .h file. Just in the .cpp and give me a test in main.cpp.thx

Comment: You can't actually "vanish" your private members. Somehow you can do this with PIpml idiom (see answer) but you still will ba able to see member declarations.

Comment: thx one more time. Besides std::string str("test") can I use std::string str="test";?

Comment: @linuxx: yes. you can. But when using `std::string("test")` you build string object with call to string constructor while in second case you are using temporary string object (one constructor call) and assignment operator. So this is mostly just performance isue. Also it should be noted that modern compilers often optimize second case to first.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string & name;` is a reference. You'll need to initialize it in the constructor, so it actually refers to something. What it refers to must exist as long as your `c` instance exists. It's not the right solution for this.

`std::string name;` is an actual variable, use this.

Comment: what about std::string *name;?

Comment: This would be the pointer to string. Find more about differences between pointers and references [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

`std::string &name` is "only" a reference to a string (a bit like a pointer). Because the name definitely belongs to the `class c`, I think it would make sense to have an instance there.

References are put to good use when passing instances around (to avoid copying).

Comment: duplication? you mean, copying

Answer (score 1):

```
const std::string&
```

is reference to a std::string, it is very important to understand the implications of that with respect to the lifetime of variables. Once the referenced variable goes away, the reference is no longer valid, and this is a very common way to f*ck up for beginning C++ programmers.

YMMV, Pick up a good tutorial first, and meanwhile, don't use references unless you know why and what you're doing

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'd use: string name; because string* name is just a pointer that needs to be given a value, and then I'd have to think of a way to clean it up later all by myself, and string& name, would be just a name that again has to be initialized.